# How to configure jsf project to use richfaces components in IBM rational application developer 8.5

Tags: jar, richfaces, ibm-rad, jsf-1.1

Mandatory Project configuration in our organization for JSF web project.

1. IDE - IBM rational application developer V.8.5
2. JSF 1.1
3. JAVA 1.4
4. Web module 2.3

I referred [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/2fad2df2-9c68-4aa3-abba-01e910211998/page/ddfd761e-744c-4738-8b41-19da5e6697a8/attachment/29de2a3a-ffc6-4502-9ce7-9143d4e114be/media/jsf%202.0%20portlet%20using%20richfaces.pdf) pdf for configuring IDE to use richfaces components but i couldn't resolved using those instructions.(If you have problem in downloading pdf go to [this web page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Rational%20Application%20Developer%20Wiki/page/JSF%202.0%20portlet%20using%20RichFaces%20with%20Rational%20Application%20Developer%20V8.5) for more details).

I have following jar files mentioned to add in lib folder.

1. cssparser-0.9.5.jar
2. guava-10.0.1.jar
3. richfaces-components-api-4.3.5.Final.jar
4. richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar
5. richfaces-core-api-4.3.5.Final.jar
6. richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar
7. sac-1.3.jar

What I have to do to list out richfaces components in palette view in Rational application developer IDE or to start using richfaces tags(manually typing tag name) in my jsf page.

Thank you.
Nagesh.N

Comment: RichFaces 4.x cannot work with JSF 1.1. You need to use JSF 2. Read carefully name of pdf from you link **Developing JSF 2.0 ...**

Comment: @Vasil Lukach, could you please suggest which version of RichFaces compatible with JSF 1.1 along with configuration setup details...

Comment: I found that RichFaces 3.1.5 works with JSF 1.1. But couldn't found configuration setup as well as RichFaces 3.1.5 components API documentation.

Comment: Try to use JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.x: [jars here](https://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/archive), [documentation here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/migrationguide/html_single/)